# Change pytest testsuite name in xml report

Tags: pytest, xunit

Because we started same tests with different interface, then take all reports and send them to jenkins. It's difficult to recognise with what interface we have errors. Before we use  nose, it has parameter "--xunit-testsuite-name", has pytest analog?
I want to change name of test suite in reports

> testsuite errors="0" failures="0" name="**pytest**" skips="0" tests="12" time="103.702"

to

> testsuite errors="0" failures="0" name="**inteface1**" skips="0" tests="12" time="103.702"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a `junit_suite_name` attribute to your Pytest config file since pytest 3.1:

```
[pytest]
junit_suite_name = my_suite
```

This can also be set in the command line:

```
pytest ... -o junit_suite_name=my_suite
```

Comment: Hi, but I want to change testsuites name form test, not in config file

Comment: You can set Pytest config with the -o argument: `pytest ... -o junit_suite_name=my_suite` since version 3.1 (also the minimum version that supports `junit_suite_name`). I updated my answer.

Comment: Can i also change classname attribute of the testsuite in the same manner?