# Differentiate between xml files in Junit Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, junit, jenkins-plugins, tox

I am running two sets of pytest tests, one for py27 and one for py37 (inside `tox` framework if it can help)

The test results are saved in two files: `test_27.xml` and `test_37.xml`

I'd like to differentiate between the Python versions in the Jenkins interface.
Is there any way to do that with Junit Jenkins plugin ?

Could you think of any workaround ?

Thanks ! 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Jenkins myself and have no idea what the Junit Jenkins plugin does, but as you mention [tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/): You can run the two environments in different pipelines running in parallel. They will each have their own reports then. You would define one pipeline calling `tox -e py27` and the other calling `tox -e py37` and you would have it all neatly separated.

The `testenv` would look something like this (see [substitutions](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html?highlight=envname#substitutions-for-virtualenv-related-sections)):

```
[testenv]
commands = pytest --junitxml=junit-{envname}.xml
```

Each pipeline would have their own reporting step, details about this can be glimpsed from [this article by Dave Hunt](http://davehunt.co.uk/2016/12/19/jenkins-pipeline-walkthrough.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I found so far: [Change pytest testsuite name in xml report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328882/change-pytest-testsuite-name-in-xml-report)