Cucumber junit-xml-formatter: How to set testsuite name (with Gradle)?
I'm producing JUnit XMLs executing Cucumber tests with Gradle. The result XML looks like this:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<testsuite name="Cucumber" time="109.736" tests="2" skipped="0" failures="0" errors="0">
<testcase classname="My Feature name" name="Scenario 1's name" time="46.108">
<system-out><![CDATA[
...
]]></system-out>
</testcase>
<testcase classname="My Feature name" name="Scenario 2's name" time="49.965">
<system-out><![CDATA[
...
]]></system-out>
</testcase>
</testsuite>

My question: Is there any way to change the testsuite's name? It's "Cucumber" for all XMLs, but I need it to contain the file name.

A suite is a collection of tests. Or feature files in this case. As there are multiple files, the Suite name can't be a single file name.

What do you need the filename for?

I need it to map the test results to their test files. There is something similar for pytest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45977572/3890673

Ah. Cucumber currently can't pass properties to plugins. So that would be impossible. But if you don't mind some programming you could fork https://github.com/cucumber/junit-xml-formatter

As M.P. Korstanje pointed out in his comment, junit-xml-formatter hard-coded "Cucumber" as the suite's name (see here). So the answer to my qquestion would be: No (besides forking said repo or processing the XML after creation, of course).
